# "TypeError: date.match is not a function" in datepicker bootsrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I got this error ""TypeError: date.match is not a function" when i try to set up a date list to be showed in datepicker

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR",
    multidate: true
});
//this dates is just a example, I already try to create from another way like:
// var data = new Array("2015-06-19", "2015-06-15") 
//and also not work!

var dates = ["2015-06-19", "2015-06-15"];
$('#datepicker').datepicker('update', datas);
```

I notice in the [doc](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdates) "Each date is assumed to be a “local” date object, and will be converted to UTC for internal use."

I don't understood what it means. Should I create a list of dates or an Array? what is the difference between them, they are not the same thing?

Comment: `dd/mm/aaaa` --- what's this?

Comment: Sorry, the correct is dd/mm/yyyy I have change because in my country  ano = year

Comment: And now - the format does not match to what you pass in `datas` array.

Comment: But it is not a problem

Comment: Do you think it makes sense? Why to have format at all then if you don't follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, I just change the last row of code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('update', datas); //to
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', datas);
```

Thanks All!

Comment: If you use `var datas = ["2015-06-19", "2015-06-15"];` your site will have problems in browsers with different regional settings. For example, in my browser, I get "05/12/24,05/12/20" [screenshot](http://s12.postimg.org/dwq2uffzh/Selection_102.png)

Answer (score 1):

A "local" `Date` object, refers to [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Some examples of how initialize it

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);

var unixTimestamp = Date.now(); // in milliseconds
```

As it's suggested in another answer, you can use `setDates`

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  language: "pt-BR",
  multidate: true,
});

var datas = [
    new Date(2015, 5, 19), //remember, months in javascript starts with 0 for january
    new Date(2015, 5, 15)
];
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDates', datas)
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jd71sqj/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is update won't take an array as its second parameter.

One option is you can use setDates

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  language: "pt-BR",
  multidate: true,
});

var datas = ["2015-06-19", "2015-06-15"];
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDates', datas)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" />
```

Or do something like

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  language: "pt-BR",
  multidate: true,
});

var datas = ["2015-06-19", "2015-06-15"];
datas.unshift('update');
var $el = $('#datepicker');
$el.datepicker.apply($el, datas)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" />
```